# What is the meaning or significance of the following Joseph Campbell quote?

Tags: monomyth, joseph-campbell

> And where we had thought to find an abomination we shall find a God.
>
> Where we had thought to slay another we shall slay ourselves.
>
> Where we had thought to travel outward we shall come to the center of our own existence.
>
> And where we had thought to be alone we shall be with all the world.

[Link](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/37475-the-hero-path-we-have-not-even-to-risk-the)

Comment: can you provide some context for your question? Are you just confused about what it means, or is this part of a homework assignment? Did you find this quote in a book or just on the website linked?

Comment: This quote was woven into the costume for Superman in the upcoming Batman v. Superman film: 
http://comicbook.com/2015/12/07/supermans-suit-in-batman-v-superman-has-a-quote-on-it/
Other than the literal meaning or the universality of the hero's journey, is there any other particular significance to this quotation that would warrant it's inclusion into Superman's costume?

Answer (score 2):

I hope my answer doesn't state the obvious... but I think you are correct in seeing this quote as the "hero's journey" in a general sense. He was bringing up the idea that the battles and journeys are ultimately about the self: understanding, accepting, conquering... and eventually seeing the divinity in knowing/accepting who we are.

The reason this is so significant in Superman (and Batman) is because we like to make Superman (and all superheroes) as perfect gods fighting the evil "out there", but the idea is that they, too must see that evil and divinity is not outside of them to be conquered. One of the things we like about these comics is that they are constantly struggling with their own humanness. Superman needed to realize that for him to become a true Superman his greatest fight is with himself not with these other enemies... So to wear the costume he needed to acknowledge this.